How to get the value of a dynamically created checkbox with CustomTkinter
I'm creating checkboxes dynamically with a for loop based on the size of the list I have, but I can't get its values.
from customtkinter import *

random_list = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Coconut', 'Dragon Fruit']


def print_checkboxes():
    print(checkbox.get())


root = CTk()
scroll_frame = CTkScrollableFrame(master=root)
scroll_frame.pack()

for i in range(len(random_list)):
    checkbox = CTkCheckBox(master=scroll_frame, text=random_list[i])
    checkbox.pack(pady=10)

button = CTkButton(master=root, text='Print', command=print_checkboxes).pack()
root.mainloop()


This returns true only for the last checkbox created by the for loop
I need a way to get the value of each one of them and save it on a list
